# One delegate Two classes

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, delegates, google-places-api

I am using a UISearchController with GoogleMap Autocomplete View controller to send data to my view controllers. 
I have a Tabbar controller and I want to send the data two my ViewController A and B.
I have done all the necessary jobs but only one ViewController gets notified when user has used the UISearchController.

I have tried setting the delegate of each tab to nil when I move to the other tab, For example if I move from ViewController A to B

I will set the delegate of A to nil and then set the delegate of B to itself.

I am kinda new to swift so Can anyone help me understand why isn't this working?

I have tried debugging my code to see is my delegate is nil and it wasn't .

Here is how i set and unset the delegate

```
 func setDelegate() {

    print("MapViewController is not nil")
    print(resultsViewController?.delegate)
    resultsViewController?.delegate = self
    print(resultsViewController?.delegate)

}

func unSetDelegate() {

    print("MapViewController is nil")
    resultsViewController?.delegate = nil

}
```

Comment: make an array of delegates an notify all delegates with a loop

Comment: @ReinierMelian im having a similar problem, can you please explain a bit more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an observer pattern, if you need that one class instance notify to a number of other instances you need make an array of delegates (called observers) and register and deregister from that notifier instance class

Further info [Wikipedia Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

**example code**

> This is the protocol that must implement any observer class

```
protocol GeotificationsManagerObserver : NSObjectProtocol{
    func nearestGeotificationsHasChanged(pgeotifications:[Geotification])
}
```

> Notifier class

```
class GeotificationsManager: NSObject {
    
    /**...*//code
    
    fileprivate var observers : [GeotificationsManagerObserver] = []

    /**...*//code

}
```

> Observers methods

```
extension GeotificationsManager
{
    func addGeotificationsManagerObserver(observer:GeotificationsManagerObserver)
    {
        for currentObs in self.observers {
            if(observer.isEqual(currentObs))
            {
                //we don't want add again
                return
            }
        }
        
        self.observers.append(observer)
    }
    
    func removeGeotificationsManagerObserver(observer:GeotificationsManagerObserver)
    {
        var observerIndex = -1
        for (index,currObserver) in self.observers.enumerated() {
            if(observer.isEqual(currObserver))
            {
                observerIndex = index
                break
            }
        }
        if(observerIndex != -1)
        {
            self.observers.remove(at: observerIndex)
        }
    }
    
    //here make the notification to all observers in observers array
    func nearestsGeotificationsHasChanged()
    {
        for currObserver in self.observers {
            currObserver.nearestGeotificationsHasChanged(pgeotifications: self.getNearesGeotifications())
        }
    }
    
}
```

**Important**
**You must remove the observer once you don't need being notified if not you will have memory issue**

Example: You can add a `UIViewController` as Observer in `viewDidAppear` and can be removed in `viewDidDisappear`